# Windows TCP keepalive sending 1 byte messages with no PSH

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, winsock

I have a traffic capture from what I believe is a windows client.  I've noticed that from time to time it sends what are identified by Wireshark as "TCP Keep-Alive", but instead of just setting ACK and sending no data, it backs up SEQ by one octet and resends that data.

(C = client, S = server, relative seq / ack)

```
(connected, data transferred back and forth)
1  C: PSH      Seq=21, Ack=41, Len=12
2  S: PSH ACK  Seq=41, Ack=33, Len=12
3  C:     ACK  Seq=33, Ack=53
4  S: PSH ACK  Seq=53, Ack=33, Len=1
5  C:     ACK  Seq=33, Ack=54
   ... 3 seconds pass ...
6  C:     ACK  Seq=32, Ack=54, Len=1 (resends the last octet from #1)
7  S:     ACK  Seq=54, Ack=33
   ...
```

Is this the normal behaviour for the windows stack when sending TCP keepalives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what a keep-alive segment is. It isn't a separate piece of protocol, it's just a redundant send with a sequence number that has already been acknowledged, to provoke an ACK with the current sequence number in reply. There's no requirement that it set the PSH flag either.

Comment: As I understood it, a TCP keep-alive should send no data.  I guess the windows implementation is different, that's all.

Comment: @Wade There is no such thing as a 'Windows implementation' of keepalive. There is just keepalive, and this is how it is implemented. You need to entertain the notion that your preconceptions weren't accurate.

Comment: Not to be too picky, and I do appreciate your answer, but there is definitely a 'Windows implementation' that sends len=1, where the Linux implementation sends len=0.

Comment: @Wade That is exactly what a TCP keepalive packet is supposed to look like. One byte of data that has already been acknowledged.

Comment: @user207421 IETF does not completely agree with you. RFC 1122 says: "An implementation SHOULD send a keep-alive segment with no data; however, it MAY be configurable to send a keep-alive segment containing one garbage octet, for compatibility with erroneous TCP implementations."